# How to parallelize this structure?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore

I'm trying to parallelize the following structure using OpenMP in C++:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2,k1,k2 = 0;
a1,a2,b1,b2; //initialized to some value
vec1,vec2;

for (i=0;i<N;++i) {
   for (j=0;j<M;++j) {
      x2 = j - a2;
      y2 = i - b2;

      func(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function changes x1,y1 values

      x2 = x1;
      y2 = y1;

      func2(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function changes x1,y1 values

      x1 += a1;
      y1 += b1;

      k1 = func3(x1,y1);

      vec2[k2] = vec1[k1];
      vec2[k2+1] = vec1[k1+1];

      k2 += 2;
   }
}
```

Could you help me?. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**EDIT:**

The last solution I've tried is:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2,k1,k2 = 0;
a1,a2,b1,b2; //initialized to some value
vec1,vec2;

#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic,1) collapse(2)
for (i=0;i<N;++i) {
   for (j=0;j<M;++j) {
      x2 = j - a2;
      y2 = i - b2;

      func(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function changes x1,y1 values

      x2 = x1;
      y2 = y1;

      func2(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function changes x1,y1 values

#pragma omp critical
{
      x1 += a1;
      y1 += b1;
}

      k1 = func3(x1,y1);

#pragma omp ordered
{
      vec2[k2] = vec1[k1];
      vec2[k2+1] = vec1[k1+1];
}

#pragma omp atomic
      k2 += 2;
   }
}
```

Resulting in a segmentation fault.

Comment: what did you tried ? what errors did you get ?

Comment: I've already edited the answer, that is one of the solutions that I've tried so far. I'm not sure about how to do it anyway, so it's just an example.

Comment: You can't. You have a lot of data dependencies.

Comment: I was afraid it is not possible due to the number of dependencies...

Comment: does `func(x1,y1,x2,y2)` uses initial values of x1 and y1, or does it just ouput them ? and what are you trying to do (the general idea) ? It would help us to help you

Comment: `func(x1,y1,x2,y2)` does not use initial values of `x1,y1`. The values are just updated inside the function. The values are different before and after the calling

Comment: is k1 just in fact a temporary to do some assignment ?

Comment: `k1` is the index of `vec1` that contains the value to update `vec2` in the index `k2`, and it is updated every iteration.

Comment: The main is filling `vec2` with reordered values of `vec1` according to some calculations that will return the correct index (`k1`). `vec1` is a vector that points to the data values of a MxN matrix.

Comment: the problem for me is this line `vec2[k2+1] = vec2[k1+1];` is vec2[k1+1] possibly assigned from a precedent loop iteration ? if it's the case then you just almost can't parallelize it

Comment: Ooop, there is a typo there, it should be `vec2[k2+1] = vec1[k1+1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108398/discussion-between-guiroux-and-finfa811).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your chat with @Guiroux and also determined that your loops are independent. The only thing that is currently carried from iteration to iteration is `k2` which can be computed directly from `i` and `j` instead (`k2 = 2*j+2*M*i`).

Therefore, your parallelized code can simply be

```
int k1, k2;
double x1,x2,y1,y2;
double a1,a2,b1,b2; //initialized to some values
double vec1[2*M*N],vec2[2*M*N]; // vec1 is read-only past this point

/* 
   NOTE: private(var) means that it may no longer have same value it had previously.
   In your case, these were all set to 0 before. After reading chat, it seems that
   they were never actually used as input anyway. As long as they are written to 
   before being read from (i.e. x1,y1 in func), no seg fault will occur.
*/
#pragma omp parallel for private(x2,y2,x1,y1,k1,k2)
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {      // I defined i,j here
   for (int j=0; j<M; ++j) {   // If you define them outside parallel for, 
                               // they must also be made private

      // variables set below are all private, so no threads will overwrite 
      // work that other threads have done
      x2 = j - a2;
      y2 = i - b2;

      func(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function sets x1,y1 values

      x2 = x1;
      y2 = y1;

      func2(x1,y1,x2,y2); // the function sets x1,y1 values

      x1 += a1;
      y1 += b1;

      k1 = func3(x1,y1);

      // k2 is never the same for 2 different values of i, 
      // so different threads will never clobber each other here:
      k2 = 2*j+2*M*i;
      vec2[k2] = vec1[k1];
      vec2[k2+1] = vec1[k1+1];

   }
}
```

You don't have to collapse both loops. As long as `N > nCoresOnYourComputer`, then you can see how work will be evenly split among all the processors.

Hopefully that all makes sense. Try and figure out in my code why I had to define certain variables `private` (vs the default `shared`), and why `k2` must be redefined as I did.

Exercise left for the reader: How else can you set `k2` (that also safely avoids race conditions), but that mostly preserves the logic that you were originally using (i.e. `k2 += 2` every iteration)?

Comment: Wow, that's an extended answer. Everything is pretty clear and the solution works pretty good, thank both you and @Guiroux for your help.